# ¿Es posible distinguir tráfico entrante de tráfico respuesta a nivel de red (IP) o transporte (TCP / UDP) en un router de manera fiable?

Tags: ip, internet-explorer, tcp, wireshark

Pregunta sencilla, posiblemente, para los expertos.

¿Alguno de los campos del paquete IP-TCP y/o IP-UDP se utiliza de manera exclusiva para determinar que el paquete es un paquete de respuesta a una petición anterior, y no una petición entrante?

Veo en un simple PING y wget a google el siguiente trafico:

```
10.0.2.15   172.217.17.14   ICMP    74  Echo (ping) request  id=0x0001, seq=2/512, ttl=128 (reply in 321)
172.217.17.14   10.0.2.15   ICMP    74  Echo (ping) reply    id=0x0001, seq=2/512, ttl=115 (request in 320)

10.0.2.15   172.217.17.14   TCP 66  50307 → 80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=256 SACK_PERM=1
172.217.17.14   10.0.2.15   TCP 60  80 → 50307 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=1460
10.0.2.15   172.217.17.14   TCP 54  50307 → 80 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=64240 Len=0
10.0.2.15   172.217.17.14   HTTP    152 GET / HTTP/1.0 
172.217.17.14   10.0.2.15   TCP 60  80 → 50307 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=99 Win=65535 Len=0
172.217.17.14   10.0.2.15   HTTP    606 HTTP/1.0 301 Moved Permanently  (text/html)
10.0.2.15   172.217.17.14   TCP 54  50307 → 80 [ACK] Seq=99 Ack=553 Win=63688 Len=0
10.0.2.15   172.217.17.14   TCP 54  50307 → 80 [RST, ACK] Seq=99 Ack=553 Win=0 Len=0
```

En este caso, todos los paquetes de respuesta, tanto el ICMP como los TCP que vuelven de google a la maquina local vienen con el flag ACK marcado a on, pero también algunos de salida van marcados igualmente

Un rato de navegación, sigo viendo el mismo patrón (wireshark)

Por tanto deduzco, que todos los paquetes de respuesta el ICMP y TCP al menos vienen marcados con ACK = 1, aunque la respuesta salga de la maquina local al server, como respuesta a su respuesta.

¿Es este campo utilizado de manera estándar por los routers para identificar el trafico "entrante", del trafico "respuesta a uno saliente anterior"?

¿Se mantendría en UDP?

¿Sería esto suficiente para identificar 100% un paquete entrante como respuesta, o sería necesario mantener una listado de todas las peticiones pendientes (IP+protocolo+puerto) para asegurar que una petición es quien dice ser?

Comment: hello?
nadie tiene respuesta para esto ?

Comment: sorry ser pesado, nadie?

Answer (score 1):

El *flag* `ACK` viene a marcar que el servidor o el cliente confirma que ha llegado un paquete que la otra maquina le envió. No necesariamente contiene una respuesta con datos. Es más, un cliente puede pedir un recurso a un servidor, y el servidor puede mandar el `ACK`, que significa que confirma que la petición ha llegado, y los datos pedidos (como una página web), por separado, o juntos (se denomina *piggybacking*).

Por tanto, si quieres saber si un mensaje, o varios, se corresponden a la respuesta de una máquina, más que mirar si llevan el *flag* `ACK` activo, lo que se mira es el número de secuencia, que identifica los mensajes que se van enviando por si algún paquete se pierde y hay que reenviarlo.

Se puede comprobar si un paquete es entrante o saliente mirando las direcciones IP de fuente y destino, y la correspondencia de qué mensaje es respuesta de cuál mirando los números de secuencia de los mensajes de las dos máquinas.

Ahora bien, con respecto a si se mantiene el comportamiento en `UDP`: no. `UDP` y `TCP` son dos protocolos muy diferentes: mientras que `TCP` va orientado a mantener una conexión (por ello hay mensajes `SYN`, `SYN ACK` y `FIN`), y mantiene un listado de los paquetes que se van enviando (de ahí que los paquetes vayan marcados con un número de secuencia), por si se pierden, para poder reenviarlos; `UDP` es un protocolo liviano, con poca lógica, no orientado a la conexión, y no se recupera ante pérdida de paquetes, por lo que no hay mensajes `SYN`, `ACK` o `FIN`.

Respondiendo a tu pregunta:

En `UDP` puedes utilizar los campos IP origen, IP destino, puerto origen y puerto destino para verificar si la máquina a la que estás enviando información te está enviando información. No tiene por qué ser un mensaje de respuesta, ya que no se establece ninguna conexión y el mensaje puede ser casual, es decir, que no tenga relación con tu paquete. El establecimiento de un posible conexión sobre UDP sería responsabilidad del protocolo de nivel superior que utilice UDP, es decir, sería en el protocolo de nivel de aplicación donde podrías saber si un paquete UDP es respuesta a uno que enviaste desde tu máquina.

En `TCP`, en cambio, sí que se puede saber, ya que se establece una conexión y los mensajes van ordenados y marcados con un número de secuencia, por lo que la combinación de IP origen, IP destino, puerto origen, puerto destino y números de secuencia te ayudarán a identificar si un mensaje es entrante, saliente, o si es respuesta de algún otro mensaje que enviaste o recibiste.

Ahora bien, si tomamos la pila TCP/IP, el modelo se divide en capas, que son: físico, enlace, red (IP), transporte (TCP/UDP) y aplicación. Has de saber que un router controla el tráfico de nivel de red, e implementa un reducido conjunto de la capa de transporte, de tal manera que le sería posible identificar mensajes y respuestas solo de TCP, y no de UDP, ya que no implementa la capa de aplicación.